# Is Salesforce planning to retire or stop supporting Outbound Messages?

Tags: workflowoutboundmessage, change-data-capture

We are evaluating whether or not to use Outbound Messages in an integration project, calling them from Flow. It's my understanding Salesforce plans on [retiring Workflow Rules](https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2021/go-with-the-flow-whats-happening-with-workflow-rules-and-process-builder), but it is not clear how much longer Outbound Messages will be supported.

We are considering using Change Data Capture as an alternative to Outbound Messages, but only if there are plans to stop supporting Outbound Messages in the near future.

Has Salesforce made any statements or publications indicating what their plan is for Outbound Messages in the near future?

Comment: The page you reference specifically states "Flow now supports calling Outbound Messages as well as Email Alerts from Workflow Actions." Why do you think they are likely to be discontinued?

Comment: https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/data-integration should be your 1st stop

Comment: @PhilW thanks for your comment. I don't make any assumptions about the longevity of Outbound Messages, which is why I raised the question. As it is related to, at least in part, to Workflow Rules, I wanted to see if others are aware of any potential end of support for it as well.

Comment: @identigral thanks for your comment. The guide does indicate Salesforce does not plan to make any further investments in Outbound Messages and suggests using caution if building integrations with it.

Comment: Worth noting the introduction of [HTTP callouts from flows](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_http_callout.htm&type=5) (GET now, POST coming)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Data Integration Salesforce Architects Guide](https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/data-integration), Salesforce recommends using caution before choosing to build with Outbound Messages:

> Use caution if you choose to build with Outbound Messages. Salesforce
> will continue supporting Outbound Messages within current functional
> capacities, but does not plan on making further investments in this
> technology.